# Wordpress single page theme - how to get the ids of the pages from the menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one problem, I have a one-page wordpress theme and I'd like to implement WP Menus inside it. I created a custom walker so I could create links like #post-slug or #page-slug instead of redirecting the user to another page, but the issue comes when I need to show the posts from the menu on the homepage.

Obviously I can't show both pages and posts in one query so the only solution would be to create two queries, but still, how can I get the ids of the posts or pages that were added in Appearance > Menus? I need just the pages or the posts and not custom links or categories/etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php the_ID();
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_ID

This function displays the ID of the post, to return the ID use [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID).

**EDIT**
I'm fairly sure you need the `wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args );` function.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I need, I need a function that returns the ids of the pages/posts I added in a custom menu in Appearance > Menus, as I said in my initial post

Comment: If you need all the ids of all pages, try `get_pages( $args );` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: I need to get the ids of the pages I set in Appearance -> Menus for a specific menu, not all the pages from the db.